# $\int_t^T 1_C\cdot A\;d\!X=1_C\cdot\int_t^T A\;d\!X$ for $C\in\mathcal F_t$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Given a semi-martingale $X$ on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\{\mathcal F_t\}_{t\le\infty},P)$, an integrand $A$ and a set $C\in\mathcal F_t$. Show: $$\int_t^T 1_C\cdot A\;d\!X=1_C\cdot\int_t^T A\;d\!X.$$

Is this statement true? How could one prove it? Where can I find the prove?

Comment: Can you prove it for simple integrands? Then it should be easy to generalise it. Keep in mind $\int_t^T\mathbf1_CA_sdX_s$ and  $\mathbf1_C$ does not depend on $s$.

Comment: @user8 Yes, for simple integrands $1_C$ is a common factor in the sum and I can factor it out. But how do I genrealize this?

Comment: How did you define the stochastic integral?

Comment: @user8 I am using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D_calculus#Semimartingales_as_integrators.

Comment: @ user4514 : Hi a stochastic integrator is not really what I would call a rigorously formalized notion could you be more specific on this ? Best regards

Comment: @user8 First, you define the integral for simple integrands. Then extend it to more general integrands $x$ as the limit in probability of the integrals of simple integrands $x_n$ approximating $x$.

Comment: @TheBridge I update the question and $X$ is now a semi-martingale. I actually do not really care how I define the integral. If you know of a meaingful stochastic integration theory where the assertion holds, I would be glad to hear it, or get pointers in this direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I will only consider the case that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion; the general case is not even more technical, but notation gets more complicated.

1. The claim holds for simple integrands. This follows directly from the definition of the stochastic integral
2. Let $f \in L^2([0,T] \times \Omega)$ be progressively measurable, i.e. $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T f^2(s) \, ds \right)<\infty.$$ Then there exists a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of simple integrands such that $$\|f_n-f\|_{L^2([0,T] \times \mathbb{P})} \to 0.$$  This implies in particular $$\|(f_n-f) 1_C\|_{L^2([0,T] \times \mathbb{P})} \leq \|f_n-f\|_{L^2([0,T] \times \mathbb{P})} \to 0. \tag{1}$$ Consequently, by the definition of the Itô integral, $$\begin{align*} \int_t^T 1_C \cdot f(s)  \, dX_s &= L^2-\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_t^T 1_C \cdot f_n(s) \, dX_s \\ &= L^2-\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1_C \int_t^T f_n(s) \, dX_s \right) \\ &= 1_C \int_t^T f(s) \, dX_s. \end{align*}$$

Comment: What does the $L^2−\lim$ stand for?

Comment: @user4514 $X = L^2-\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n$ iff $\|X_n-X\|_{L^2} \to 0$. So, yes, in more general versions of the stochastic integral the limit in probability is used to define it, but this doesn't change a thing. (And since I assumed that $(X_t)_t$ is a Brownian motion, there is nothing wrong about the $L^2$-limit.) [Please do not delete your comments.]

Comment: Why not? If they did not make sense?

Comment: @user4514 Two reasons: 1. Your question about limit in probability vs. limit in $L^2$ wasn't a bad one. Other readers might have been interested. 2. My comments look out of place if you remove yours.

Comment: Ok, I won't. One more question: Why can I pull the $1_C$ out of the $L^2$ limit? (Because it is a norm?)

Comment: @user4514 It is exactly the same argumentation as in (1). Since $$\left\| \int_t^T f_n(s) \, dX_s - \int_t^T f(s) \, X_s \right\|_{L^2} \to 0$$ it follows that $$\left\| 1_C \int_t^T f_n(s) \, dX_s - 1_C \int_t^T f(s) \, dX_s \right\|_{L^2} \leq \left\| \int_t^T f_n(s) \, dX_s - \int_t^T f(s) \, X_s \right\|_{L^2} \to 0.$$ (Note that $\|1_C X\|_{L^2} \leq \|X\|_{L^2}$ holds for any random variable $X$.) Consequently, $$1_C \int f(s) \, dX_s = L^2-\lim \left( 1_C \int f_n(s) \, dX_s \right).$$