# Property of stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have to show next property of stochastic integration.

Let $X$ be adapted integrand, for which we know that $E[\int_0^T X_s^2 ds] < \infty$. Let $0 \leq s < t \leq T $ and we have some $W \in F_s$ ($F_s$ is $\sigma$-algebra) and we know $E[\int_s^t W^2 X_s^2 ds] < \infty$.

Show that $\int_s^t W X_u dBu = W \int_s^t X_u dBu$.

I think I should start first with simple integrands and then make construction on other, but I am not sure if it is obvious how to make this on simple integrands.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/706786/

Comment: Sorry for late response, but I have one more question about my exercise @saz. In a link that you put here, you are using indicator function. But in my case I am wondering if it also holds that from $E[ (\int_s^t (X_u - X_u^n ) dBu)^2 ] \to 0 $ when $n \to \infty $ it implies that $E[ ( \int_s^t (WX_u - WX_u^n ) dBu)^2 ] \to 0 $ when $n \to \infty $ and how do I see it as long as $W$ is not indicator function. Thanks.

Comment: Because of the linearity of the integral, the identity extends from indicator functions to simple functions. For general $W$ approximate $W$ by a sequence of $\mathcal{F}_s$-measurable simple functions

Comment: Isn't this a deliberate duplicate of your previous question?